# Anyway to scroll through Carbon Design System content switchers?

Tags: reactjs, websphere, user-experience, carbon-design-system

Considering switching to using tabs since they allow for horizontal scrolling, but this would be a large-sclae shift for our software, so was wondering if there's a simpler workaround short term for horizontally scrolling [content switchers](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/content-switcher/usage/) that won't mess up its responsiveness.

please & thank yous (((sorry if you went what a nooooob)))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.